# R gRain package error

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I am using gRain package to create a bayesian network. The following is the code that I tried from the example:

```
data("cad1")
cad.dag <- dag(~ CAD:Smoker:Inherit:Hyperchol + AngPec:CAD + Heartfail:CAD + QWave:CAD)
cad.cpt <- extractCPT(cad1, cad.dag, smooth = 0.1)
```

The last line throws an error:

```
"Error in nw$nodes : $ operator not defined for this S4 class".
```

Can someone help?

Update: This problem seems to have occurred due to a conflick with bnlearn package. Got sorted out now.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have occurred due to a conflict with bnlearn package. Got sorted out now.